# Form search serialise GET params

Tags: php, forms

I am working on product search for a classified ads project. Based on category filters are changed. Following is my model structure

1) Category

2) Category has many fields so I have `category_field` and `fields` table

3) Field may be of type select so another table is `field_option`, Field may have many options.

Following is my search url initially when user visits the page

```
https://store.dev/search?category=shoes
```

So I get category from url and search data and collects `fields` in `$fields` table and my search form is following

```
{{ html()->form('GET',route('frontend.ajax.search'))->id('search_filter')->attribute('role','form')->open() }}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title mb-1">Category</h4>
            {{ html()->select('category',$categories, request()->has('category') ? request('category') : '')->class('form-control') }}
            <hr>

            @if(isset($fields) && count($fields) > 0)

                @foreach($fields as $field)
                    @if($field->type == 'select')
                        <h4 class="card-title mt-4 mb-1">{{ $field->name }}</h4>

                        @if($field->searchable_range)
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col">
                                    {{ html()->select('min_'.$field->slug,$field->pluck_options)
                                             ->class('form-control range-slider')
                                             ->attribute('data-id',$field->id)
                                             ->placeholder('Min') }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    {{ html()->select('max_'.$field->slug,$field->pluck_options)
                                             ->class('form-control range-slider')
                                             ->attribute('data-id',$field->id)
                                             ->placeholder('Max') }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @else
                                <div class="overflow-auto options-list">
                                   @foreach($field->pluck_options as $slug => $value)
                                        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-3">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="{{ $field->slug }}[]" value="{{ $slug }}">
                                            <span class="custom-control-label">
                                               <span class="text-dark">{{ $value }}</span>
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                   @endforeach
                                </div>
                            @endif                                    
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif

            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Apply Filter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{ html()->form()->close() }}
```

When I submit the form checkbox array are submitted like following

```
https://store.dev/search?category=shoes&brand=nike&brand=adidas&min_price=100&max_price=
```

How can I remove the empty fields and combine the same fields in array like

```
https://store.dev/search?category=shoes&brand=nike,adidas&price=100,1000
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : Instead of using basing serial data, you can send JSON parameters (POST or GET) . Off course this put extra work on the Javascript side to process the forma datas and send them back in AJAX.

Option 2 : use also POST request with input field with name="price[min]" and name="price[max]". In that case you can get them on PHP side using $_POST['price'] and then you get an array .